# android quiz moving between questions

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

So I'm currently making a quiz app in Android and am nearing the end.  I'm able to shuffle the questions and each one's respective questions.  Because of the randomness each time the activity is selected, I'm not sure of a clear way to go about moving between questions.

The only way I can think of at the moment (and it seems like the least intuitive method) is to create an activity for each question and insert the appropriate array number in each, ie. enter variables for `QUESTION = question[4].questionString, ANSWER_ONE = question[4].answerString[0], ANSWER_TWO = question[4].answerString[1]`...etc. then for the next one insert the same but for [5], and so on.  Each activity represents one block of the 'question' array.  I feel like there is, or should be, a more practical way to implement this.

I've looked slightly into fragments and viewpager, but I'm not too familiar with those (and any other options) to be able to determine which would be the ideal (or even practical) way to go.  So what options do I have?  And are any options clearly the best?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just update the UI to the new question. That way you'd have just one activity for handling all the questions.

Every time the user clicks an answer or chooses next question button, you could update the UI to show new question.

Comment: That, in theory, is definitely something I wanted to attempt.  It was my first and most hopeful idea because of its simplicity.  I just wasn't sure if it was logical and would work.  But if it came with too many downfalls, I was also curious about other viable options.

Comment: It does work :) and yes it is very simplistic. Once you have all your questions in an array list, you can have a method that has access to all the UI components and takes an int(index of the question in the array list) as a param. You can then call that method with the index of question to update the UI to that question.

Comment: So every time a user selects an answer or presses the skip question button, you could call that method with a new index.

Comment: Would the method simply update the parameters of the UI objects or would it need to recall the activity(itself) to update?

Comment: Basically, I'm not entirely sure how to implement that.  I started searching and found a possibility that included calling the activity with a new intent?  I couldn't understand it.

Comment: just update the data of the UI elements. For example:
`methodToUpdateQuestion(){
Button a1_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OptionA);
a1_button.setText("A. Option A");
...find other elements and change the data
}`

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying.  But in my scenario, when the user selects the answer, the correct answer is highlighted green, and all the answer buttons are disabled to prevent them from selecting more than one answer.  Is there a way to reset the screen with the new variables (array counter for new question/answers) so that the buttons refresh and such as well?  Or would I have to unfreeze the buttons and un-highlight them as well, to "imitate" a refreshing of the screen.  I'm just not sure exactly what it is that I want to do because I'm not sure of the options available for such a task.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do and I have implemented with just one activity. When you first start out set a counter to 0. Now pass this to a method which enables all controls and set the questions from array list according to the current counter '0'.
Now when the user selects an answer, increase the counter and disable the buttons. `optionA.setClickable(flase);`. Now when users wants a new question you can call the first method which enables the buttons and sets question according to the new index '1'.

Comment: just change text and reenable the buttons. Maybe do some animation during that time

Comment: _unfreeze the buttons and un-highlight them as well, to "imitate" a refreshing of the screen_ is way faster than making a new activity for every question and modular